# Get latest 3 comments for a list of posts

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

Currently I'm running one query to get all posts for a user, then in the loop for that, I am querying for the latest 3 comments for that particular post.  Super inefficient; I'm querying over and over again for every post.

I would like to consolidate my queries so that I query just once for all posts, and just once for all comments for those particular posts.  At the moment I have a comma-separated list that I made for all posts for this user (e.g. "1,5,18,9")

`posts` table:

- `posts`.id
- `posts`.userid

`comments` table:

- `comments`.id
- `comments`.relid (this is the postid)
- `comments`.userid

The query should use the $posts_list I have, which is the comma-separated list of posts.  Or a subselect for all posts for this user, but that seems inefficient since I already have the post list in a string.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: For better answers sake, you could also include your current script. So people can be certain of the loop order. However, might not be necessary. Just check, if you are getting quality answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT p.id, p.userid, c.id, c.userid
  FROM posts p
  JOIN (
    SELECT c1.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM comments c1
    LEFT JOIN comments c2
      ON c2.relid = c1.relid AND c2.id <= c1.id
    GROUP BY c1.relid, c1.id
    ) c
  ON p.id = c.relid
WHERE rank < 4
```

And add condition you need, i.e. - WHERE p.userid IN (1,5,18,9).